# Open-source framework for online data presentation

Tags: open-source, framework, data, presentation

I'm looking for a sort of free framework or base software to develop a web application with the following features:

- interactively present data (tables and visualisations) that are automatically provided and generated by custom SQL, R, Python and/or HTML code
- manage and systemize the contents for both admins and users
- provide input forms to add additional data for users (resp. the possibility for write access via custom content)
- manage users and grant/restrict access to the site alltogether or single areas/pages using customized profiles
- built-in data and interface management would be great but not mandatory
- responsive front-end
- state-of-the-art security

I don't mind some development effort, as long as it can be done with the languages mentioned above plus some PHP. Less restrictions and a modern front-end are more important than easy handling.